# What is the best pattern for WPF events?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Hey, i'm extending some WPF controls, and need to implement some custom events. I've read around about the 'event' keyword and method groups, but im not sure how to implement this in code. Would anyone be able to provide a simple example of a custom event/handler/etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WPF, it's best to create the custom events as Routed events. Here's a tutorial about how to do that at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288.aspx. And this is a broader introduction to Routed events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx.